# Need help, want to display different events for each day in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I want to display different event for each day in fullcalendar from a json encoded array.

if employees offday exist display offdays which is coming from another table in json encoded array.

First query return:

```
"[
    {"id":4901,"title":4901,"start":"2018-01-01","end":"2019-04-30"},
    {"id":4901,"title":4901,"start":"2018-01-01"
]"
```

Second query:

```
"[
    {"id":4901,"offday":0},
    {"id":4901,"offday":6}
]"
```

Blade view jquery fulcalendar code:

```
    var emps = {!! $emps !!};
    var empsoffdays = {!! $emps_offdays !!};
    var startdate = emps[0].start;
    var enddate = emps[0].end;

    var stdate = new Date(startdate);
    var st = stdate.getTime();

    var endate = new Date(enddate);
    var en = endate.getTime();

    //console.log(endate);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
          },
         events: [
            {
                title  : '',
                start  : startdate,
                end :enddate,
                allDay : false // will make the time show
            }
        ]
    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource',        
        function(start, end,timezone,callback) {
            // When requested, dynamically generate a
            // repeatable event for every monday.
            var events = [];       
            var monday = 1;
            var one_day = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            for (loop = stdate.getTime();
                 loop <= endate.getTime();
                 loop = loop + one_day) {
                var column_date = new Date(loop);
                if (column_date.getDay() == 1) {   
                    events.push({
                        title: emps[0].timetable_check_in,
                        start: startdate,
                        end: enddate,
                        allDay: false
                    });
                }
            } 
            callback( events );
        }
    );
```

each day should display tile which is timetable timing and offdays should diplay title offday from start date to end date[what i was able to achive][1\

Comment: can you make a fiddle. also in second query no date is available

Comment: js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fullstackhash/6apqr7nb/2/

Comment: it's unclear what the problem is...what exact issue are you facing? You've described what you want, but not what is going wrong. You've added a fiddle, but what should we be looking for in this fiddle? What is the issue, and how should we use the fiddle to reproduce it? I'm not sure what I am supposed to be fixing...